# Hiding CheckBoxes And Edit Buttons in a RadTreeList

Tags: c#, telerik, dynamics-crm-2011, radtreelist

I'm new to the "Telerik"-controls and I have a few questions!  First of all, I'll give you a small resume of what we want to achieve and how I did it for now.

The customers has several clients who come to present themselves and they need to fill in their qualities (language skills, education, ....).  Therefor we've created some templates (that already contains some crucial data).  The templates can be hierarchical => Language Skill Dutch has two children : "Writing", "Speaking".  They see that in an Hiearchical treeview (for now).

If they select the item in that tree, they automatically create a quality (with the templateid, contactid, etc...) for that type of template.  Each time they call the treeview for that contact, the template who has a quality will be checked!  And if they click on "Edit", they'll be able chaging some info of the quality.

That's in short what it does now and what's behind it.  Now, they wanted a nicer looking method without having popups and such (everything in one screen).  Then i found the "RadTreeList" of telerik.  But for now I'm having the following problems :

- The root of the tree can't be selected (best would be that the checkbox is hidden) => how do I achieve this?
- Is it possible to hide the "EDIT"-button on the root?  The root should never be selected on his own (no qualities for root elements).

**So the big question, how can I take an item while looping through the whole treelist collection and say that I don't want to show checkbox and such?**

With my treeview I iterated through all the nodes and then I did the needed modifications. But 1 => It was slow, 2 => It looked that nice, 3 => It didn't match they look of the CRM 2011.

What i've already achieved is showing everything hiearchical and select the "Node-Templates" (if I can call it so) that contains Qualities.

Hopefully you have enough info... **If there are better alternatives**, I'm open for everything, but it's kind off urgent, cause we'll have a demo-session soon :)

Info => It has to be in ASP.NET (C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that you cannot select the 'root' of the treelist, but you can place an item in the first column to add new items at root level as illustrated here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treelist/examples/dataediting/net35automaticdataediting/defaultcs.aspx.

To hide the edit button for root level items, listen to the ItemCreated event, locate the edit button in the root items only and set its Visible property to false. This should work for checkboxes or other server controls inside the treelist rows and you do not have to perform explicit loops through the items later on.